# What can we non experts do to make beta successful?

Tags: discussion

Since I am novice to MMA, what can I do to help [mathematica.stackexchange.com](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) in this beta version?

I mean is it better to ask pre-intermediate or intermediate level question, or not to ask a question at all.

Or is there any other way we can help?

Comment: This has become more of an issue as we grow - we probably need more intermediate users. Incidentally balboa still visits the site regularly and was last seen two days ago (on mma.SE not on meta).

Answer (score 33):

In my opinion, it's better to ask real questions that you have about mathematica, not worrying about the level of expertise.

Comment: I must second this, and I'd third it, if I had the votes.

Comment: And please...let's remember to upvote the questions, not just the answers!

Comment: Agreed. Even veterans can learn from solutions given to naive pre-intermediate questions. Many professional programmers have bad habits and fossilized methods which they are reluctant to change until facing the optimal solution.

Comment: Agree with both the answer and all comments.  The best question is a real question you have.  No need to make up questions just to push the site, as you can see we're not short on them at all :-)

Comment: @IstvánZachar +1 on the "bad habits" issues. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6617511/758485) of mine where I learned about my own.

Comment: My impression is that "easy" or "general" questions receive many varied answers, which is excellent if you're learning (like me). There is no substitute for effort, but there's no point in reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 12):

If your question isn't answered by typing it into a search engine or in the Mathematica help, it's probably intermediate enough to be asked here.

Comment: Some of the shorthand notations, like `@` and `/@` are impossible to search for.

Comment: Searching for `@`/`/@` yields one result each, which is the help page for `Prefix`/`Map`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant searchable in Google. Of course they're searchable in the help.